# Pandas Resampler.max() fails with "ValueError: Wrong number of items"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas to process and plot data from a CSV file. The original script is from [here](https://gist.github.com/erget/d9a1cee00052f400589cc5db78884f49) and I was able to run it successfully a few years ago. Now, however, even with the same dataset it always fails with an exception that I don't understand.

This is the code I'm using at the moment. I've split the second to last line of the original file to be able to pinpoint the origin of the exception:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Plot bank account balance in CSV-MT940 format based on a starting balance."""

import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument("filename", help="File to parse")
parser.add_argument("start_balance", help="Balance at beginning of file", type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Import after argument parsing to reduce startup time if help flag passed/invalid arguments
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

verlauf = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser(args.filename), sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1", decimal=",")
verlauf["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(verlauf.Buchungstag, format="%d.%m.%y")
verlauf = verlauf.reindex(index=verlauf.index[::-1])
verlauf["Kumulativer Umsat"] = verlauf.Betrag.cumsum()
verlauf["Kontostand"] = verlauf["Kumulativer Umsat"] + args.start_balance
verlauf.index = verlauf.Date
step1 = verlauf.resample("D")
step2 = step1.max()  # <- this is where it fails
step3 = step2.interpolate()
step4 = step3.Kontostand
step4.plot()
plt.show()
```

I was able to boil the input file down to the following:

```
"Buchungstag";"Betrag";"Info"
"08.05.20";"1,00";""
"08.05.20";"1,00";"some info"
```

The exception I am getting looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/./plot_expenses.py", line 24, in <module>
    step2 = step1.max()  # <- this is where it fails
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 957, in f
    return self._downsample(_method, min_count=min_count)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1080, in _downsample
    result = obj.groupby(self.grouper, axis=self.axis).aggregate(how, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 945, in aggregate
    result, how = aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py", line 579, in aggregate
    return obj._try_aggregate_string_function(arg, *args, **kwargs), None
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 315, in _try_aggregate_string_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1676, in max
    return self._agg_general(
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1024, in _agg_general
    result = self._cython_agg_general(
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1015, in _cython_agg_general
    agg_mgr = self._cython_agg_blocks(
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1118, in _cython_agg_blocks
    new_mgr = data.apply(blk_func, ignore_failures=True)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 425, in apply
    applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 380, in apply
    return self._split_op_result(result)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 416, in _split_op_result
    result = self.make_block(result)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 286, in make_block
    return make_block(values, placement=placement, ndim=self.ndim)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2742, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "/home/max/Entwicklung/python/plot_expenses/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 142, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2
```

Maybe it's just my limited experience with Pandas, but this error message is incredibly unhelpful to me.

I have noticed that first number in the error message corresponds to the number of non-empty values of the shorter row (in this case the first) minus one, while the second number corresponds to the number of non-empty values of the longer row minus one. The order of the rows doesn't matter. Meaning, that the following CSV file results in the message "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 3":

```
"Buchungstag";"Betrag";"Info";"asdf"
"08.05.20";"1,00";"some info";"a"
"08.05.20";"1,00";"";"a"
```

If both rows have the same number of empty values, there is no exception.

Other than that, I'm pretty lost, even after digging around in the Pandas code for about two hours. I'd really appreciate any help from somebody with more experience with Pandas than me.

Comment: As you already noticed, the issue is due to `na` values in some of the columns. You can get around this by using `keep_default_na=False` in `read_csv` to get empty strings instead of `na` values in the `Info` column.

Comment: @Stef thank you, that did indeed fix it! Why does Resampler.max() choke on `na` values?

Comment: I couldn't find a real explanation for it, maybe someone more knowledgeable of the internal workings for resample/groupby can explain it.

Comment: @Stef ok. Your suggestion was still very helpful since I didn't make the connection with the `na` values. If you want to post it as a short answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than addressing the root cause.

The issue is due to `na` values in some of the columns. You can get around this by using `keep_default_na=False` in `read_csv` to get empty strings instead of `na` values in the `Info` column:

```
verlauf = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser(args.filename), sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1", decimal=",", keep_default_na=False)
```